# How to set game render to draw objects in some order (queue)?

Tags: game-engine

In the scene with the objects of transparent such as clouds, water I see is not correct sorting on renedering, would like to see if you can somehow manually set the queue for rendering some objects?

Comment: With transparency, objects should be sorted from farthest to nearest so they display properly, if a game engine does not sort the vertices for you then there is still sometimes the option to draw the whole objects in the order you want so that transparency works properly.  This seems to be what he is asking.  Here's a link to the first page that came up for the search terms I used.  http://www.sjbaker.org/steve/omniv/alpha_sorting.html

Comment: Here's a mesh tool that may help http://www.pasteall.org/pic/76924.  Ei voi, I mistankely cut off the bottom of the image.  It can be found under Edit Mode-> Select -> Sort Elements->